# Inductor current

Tags: voltage

Posting from my phone so pardon the terrible pictures.

I am reading Daniel Hart’s “Power Electronics”

I am still in school so my math skills are in the works and I have not seen everything I need to see. 
I do not know what the symbol of integration here is... what are they integrating with respect to if not time??
what is that upside down y symbol called and why is it used here? 
Perhaps it is something simple but I have never seen that and it threw me off.

[image: il]
 Furthermore down the page: why are they using Vcc/L for current through the inductor? When the formula calls for 
V/R 
[image: c]

[image: g]

Comment: Regarding your first image, the integral is from 0 to t, and you can't use the end or start variable (as t is in this case) as "dt". So they use another "dummy-variable" in t's place in the functions. - In case you feel that I'm just mumbling, understand that  \$\int_a^bf(x)dx\$ is **equivalent** to \$\int_a^bf(r)dr\$

Comment: The upside down 'Y' is the symbol for wavelength, the inverse of frequency. You should read a bit more...

Comment: It would have been better had they used the Greek symbol for 't', tau (\$\tau\$), instead of the Greek lambda (\$\lambda\$).

Comment: @Sparky256 Author stated he is still in school. I assume that means he _is_ still reading, but hasn't encountered 'everything' yet.

Comment: It's not actually \$\frac{V_{CC}}{L}\$ that they use, but rather \$\frac{V_{CC}t}{L}\$. That is because they 'took' (colloquial for: calculated) the integral \$ \frac{1}{L}\int_0^tV_{CC}(\tau)d\tau = \frac{1}{L}\int_0^tV_{CC}d\tau = \frac{1}{L}V_{CC}\int_0^td\tau = \frac{1}{L}V_{CC}t = \frac{V_{CC}t}{L} \$. This is when the switching MOSFET is on, forcing the voltage over the inductor \$L\$ to be \$V_{CC}\$, a constant voltage which is independent of time t.

Comment: The inductor is considered here to be 'ideal', with zero resistance (\$R=0\$), so the formula for the inductor actually isn't \$I=V/R\$ but, as you know, \$ I = \frac{1}{L}\int_0^tV(\tau)d\tau \$.

Answer (score 3):

The integration

$$
i_L(t) = \frac{1}{L}\int_0^tv_L(\lambda)d\lambda + i_L(0)
$$

uses the Greek letter lambda to avoid another \$t\$ within the integral, *but it is still time*. You can choose whatever letter you want really, my references typically used the letter \$u\$:

$$
i_L(t) = \frac{1}{L}\int_0^tv_L(u)du + i_L(0)
$$

which is equivalent to the previous equation.

> why are they using Vcc/L for current through the inductor?

The integral is the *accumulated sum*, or the *area* under the curve that you want to integrate. It is the reverse operation of taking a derivative, which calculates the *slope* of a curve.

In the reference example, the author indicates that the voltage across the inductor is *constant*, or \$v_L(t) = V_{CC}\$. So this means that the integral can be calculated:

$$\begin{align}
i_L(t) &= \frac{1}{L}\int_0^t V_{CC}d\lambda + i_L(0) \\
&= \frac{V_{CC}}{L}\int_0^t 1\cdot d\lambda
\end{align}$$

The last integral is the *area* under a constant value, which is the area of a rectangle with height \$1\$ and width \$t\$ (\$\lambda\$ goes from \$0\$ to \$t\$), which means that

$$
i_L(t) = \frac{V_{CC}}{L} \int_0^t 1\cdot d\lambda = \frac{V_{CC}}{L}\cdot t
$$

Like shown in the book.